# How do i keep initial route with nested navigation with React Navigation v5?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

First let me state that I know how to navigate from one nested page to another using react navigation. However, whenever i navigate to a nested screen that is not the initial route, that screen now become the first screen whenever i navigate back to that nested stack.

**Example**.

- Parent Navigator

  - Nested Stack Navigator 1

    - screen A (Initial Route)
    - screen B
  - Nested Stack Navigator 2

    - screen C (Initial Route)
    - screen D
  - Nested Stack Navigator 2

    - screen E (Initial Route)
    - screen F

Normally when navigating from one stack to `Nested Stack Navigator 2` the I use the following.

```
navigation.navigate('Nested Navigator 2');
```

Which takes me to `screen C`, this is the expected behaviour. However, whenever i'm navigating from another stack to `screen D`, I notice that whenever i navigate back to `Nested Stack Navigator 2` with the above code it no longer opens up `screen C` it opens up `screen D` instead.

This is how I navigate to `screen D` from another stack.

```
navigation.navigate('Nested Navigator 2', { screen: 'screen D', initial: false });
```

Whenever this is used `screen D` acts as the initial route, event though I specified `initial: false` in the navigation call. Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

once you navigate to a another component other than intial route component, of  a Nested Stack Navigation, `navigation.navigate('Nested Navigator 2');` will not work

Initial your navigation stack will look this on intial routes

```js
[
 { name: ScreenA },
 { name: ScreenC },
 { name: ScreenE }
]
```

but whenever you navigate from sreen C to Screen D, Screen D will route will not inserted at the end of the stack , since it is Nested Navigation two

```js
[
 { name: ScreenA },
 { 
   name: NestedNavigator,
   [
    { name: screenC }, 
    { name: screenD }
   ]
 },
 { name: ScreenE }
]
```

so you will need to use,
navigation.navigate('Nested Navigator 2', { screen: 'screen D' });
that is because stack changes when you navigate to a screen other than initial route,

you will need to reset routes on on Nested Component , i.e. whenever you navigate to screen D, reset route stack using commonActions, set screen, this will update the stack , and remove screen D from the stack.

```js
import { CommonActions } from '@react-navigation/native';

componentDidMount() {
   this.props.navigation.addListener('blur', () => {
            this.props.navigation.dispatch(
                CommonActions.reset({
                  index: 1,
                  routes: [
                    { name: 'ScreenC' },
                    
                  ],
                })
              );
        });
    }
```

if you want to remove a certain route only instead of resetting whole navigation

```js
 this.props.navigation.dispatch(state => {
            // Remove the route from the stack
            const routes = state.routes.filter((r => r.name !== 'ScreenC' ));
        
            return CommonActions.reset({
              ...state,
              routes,
              index: routes.length - 1,
            });
          });
```

Comment: Thanks you are right, it does override the default navigation state. The fix i did was to always specify with screen i'm going to since the initial route is no longer going to work.