# How to navigate in a screen which is not defined because of a variable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, tabnavigator

When I am in the login screen I would like once the user logs in that it is also redirected to the 'Home' screen but currently, I have an error telling me that the Home is not defined what is normal ...

```js
{isAuth ? (
    <BottomTab.Screen name='Home' component={Home} />
): (
<>
    <BottomTab.Screen name='Connexion' component={Login} />
    <BottomTab.Screen name='Inscription' component={Register} />
</>
```

I don't really know how to use contexts yet but I think it might simplify the thing but in the meantime I would just like to be able to navigate from Login to Home.

Comment: You need to add home into <Stack.Navigator/> .

Comment: A stack Navigator ? But where?

Comment: As docs say, you don't need to navigate when you're using this pattern. When user logs out, it'll navigate to Home automatically. So you can just remove your navigate('Home') code and it'll work as expected. Don't change your conditional and reset manually according to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because Home stack is not added due to your condition

```
{isAuth ? (
    <BottomTab.Screen name='Home' component={Home} />
): (
<>
    <BottomTab.Screen name='Connexion' component={Login} />
    <BottomTab.Screen name='Inscription' component={Register} />
</>
```

According to your code , if isAuth true,  you only include Home  Screen and if it is false you only include Connexion and Incription, you need to include all three Screen in order to navigate between them

```
<BottomTab.Screen name='Home' component={Home} />
<BottomTab.Screen name='Connexion' component={Login} />
 <BottomTab.Screen name='Inscription' component={Register} />
```

, you need to move your condition to some other place, like on button click, also in stack we have initialRouteProp.

```
  <Stack.Navigator
                    initialRouteName={isAuth() ? Home : Login}
                  
                >
```

For Tab Navigator we have intialRoute prop, you can check intial route based on your isauth() function

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function MyTabs() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator initialRoute={isAuth() ? Home : Login}>
```

For MaterialTopTabNavigator , in initialRouteName i pass isAuth condition , if true it set Home screen as initial screen , if false Login will be the initial screen.

```
const BottomTab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

  <BottomTab.Navigator initialRouteName={isAuth ? Home : Login}>

    <BottomTab.Screen name='Home' component={Home} />
   <BottomTab.Screen name='Connexion' component={Login} />
   <BottomTab.Screen name='Inscription' component={Register} />
```

If don't Login and register screens on after home, you reset the stack and remove routes you don't need

```
 this.props.navigation.dispatch(state => {
            // Remove the Login and Register from Stack from the stack
            const routes = state.routes.filter((r => r.name !== 'Connexion' && r => r.name !== 'Inscription' ));
        
            return CommonActions.reset({
              ...state,
              routes,
              index: routes.length - 1,
            });
          });
```

then on later on any event such as Logout click you cam readd Login Route

```
this.props.navigation.dispatch(
                CommonActions.reset({
                  index: 1,
                  routes: [
                    { name: 'Login' },
                    
                  ],
                })
              );
        });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But isAuth is only a variable and not a function so I can't call it like this 'isAuth ()'. 
I use for my by a MaterialTopTabNavigator that I place at the bottom. 
Didn't quite understand what to do? Do I have to add a stack navigator?

Comment: the problem is not due to TabNavigator, you will need to place your isAuth variable, some other place, such as in an initialRoute prop, check if MaterialTopTabNavigator has one

Comment: Yes MaterialTopTabNavigator has 'initialRouteName'.

Comment: i have updated my answer for MaterialTop, kindly check if it is helpful

Comment: Ok ok I see what you have done is working well but me the behavior I am looking for is really only showing the Home screen if the user is connected and vice versa if the user is not connected then he cannot access only Login and Register. The current behavior shows all screens whether connected or not.

Comment: well if you place both on different stacks and conditionally execute one stack i.e. Home, user will not be able to access Login when logged out

Comment: Ok i will try this tanks

Comment: I have further updated my answer, may you need reset route programitacally, for detail you can check following answer also
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65819611/how-do-i-keep-initial-route-with-nested-navigation-with-react-navigation-v5/65820904#65820904