# Remove tabnavigator from screen in createStackNavigator

Tags: react-native, tabnavigator

I want to remove tabnavigator from screen2

```
const switchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  registration: createStackNavigator({
    first: First,
    second: Second,
    third: Third,

  }),
  tabScreens: createBottomTabNavigator({
    Index: createStackNavigator({
      screen1: Screen1,
      screen2: Screen2,
    }),
  index2: Index2
  }),
});
```

I want to remove tabNavigator in screen2. How can i handle this ? it should be in createStackNavigator.

Comment: why add screen 2 in tabNavigator if you don't need tab in screen 2, just put it outside tab separately in main stack

Comment: @ShahidNawaz i want to screen1 to screen 2 and when i want to go back screen2 to screen1 i want to find screen1 as i left

Comment: screen 1 will not have any effect , if you take screen 2 two out of the tab navigator
you can check following answer, it might give you an idea.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65819611/how-do-i-keep-initial-route-with-nested-navigation-with-react-navigation-v5/65820904#65820904

Comment: and this one also,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65831263/how-to-navigate-in-a-screen-which-is-not-defined-because-of-a-variable/65831535#65831535

Comment: @ShahidNawaz so how can go back screen2 to screen1 ? if i do navigation.navigate('screen1') screen1 will re render i mean  it will not find as i left

Comment: i mean, think that 2 buttons in screen1, when i click button2  backgroundcolor of screen1 will be red  then when i go "screen2" then go back "screen1" backgroundcolor: red will disappear.  @ShahidNawaz

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use the below code in Screen2 Component like:

```
import React from "react"
import { View, Text } from "react-native";

const Screen2 = props => {
    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
            <Text>SCREEN 2</Text>
        </View>
    );
};

Screen2.navigationOptions = navData => {
    return {
         tabBarVisible: false,
    };
};

export default Screen2;
```

it will remove the bottom tab bar for the specific screen containing in createBottomTab Navigator

Comment: this is work if screen2 is in createBottomTabNavigator however it is in createStackNavigator so this is not work :(

Comment: If you would like to hide the bottom tab in stack navigation than you have to check for the state index of stack navigation for hiding in specific screen like

OtherScreen.navigationOptions = navData => {
 return {
  tabBarVisible: navData.navigation.dangerouslyGetParent().state.index > 0 ? false : true,
 };
};